# Enable SMS OTP on login and through API on identity server WSO2 5.7

Tags: authentication, wso2, sms, wso2-identity-server, totp

I want to enable SMS OTP on identity server WSO2 5.7.0. I followed this documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+SMS+OTP: first the disable otp sms under user profile appeared as a text box instead of checkbox, and second, on login, the page redirected to the login page again. For users with no phone number, it displayed an update phone number screen but with error on update.

Note: i am using nexmo as SMS provider and calling its API from postman sends an sms successfully.

Once the above is working fine, i want to trigger this SMS OTP outside the login scope. Is this possible? i did not find anything related to this under the 5.7.0 IS documentation.

**Some errors from the log file:**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-20 13:47:13,962]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain} -  Interceptor for {http://authz.endpoint.oauth.identity.carbon.wso2.org/}OAuth2AuthzEndpoint has thrown exception, unwinding now 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:370)
```

And:

````
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.smsotp.exception.SMSOTPException: User does not exist in the User Store.
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.smsotp.SMSOTPUtils.verifyUserExists(SMSOTPUtils.java:150)

TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-20 13:46:09,025] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} -  Failed to get the parameters from authentication xml file.  
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException: Failed to get the parameters from authentication xml file. 
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.smsotp.SMSOTPAuthenticator.initiateAuthenticationRequest(SMSOTPAuthenticator.java:164)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to authenticate users with SMS OTP without having another authentication step such as basic authentication, it is not supported in the product at the moment.

You might be able to implement a custom authenticator, but have to be cautions about rate limiting and security issues with SMS such as SIM swapping, etc.

Comment: I am just trying to use the feature as a second factor authentication

Comment: What is in the first step? Also please share the full stacktraces of the error logs